# Angular UI performance testing as TPS

Tags: angular, pcf

We have an Angular application which is hosted in PCF. The flow is, when user hit the application URL https://abcd.com, it goes to NGINX servers and NGINX will forward to PCF, from the PCF Angular code will be served.

Our backend API's are configured as 300TPS(300 Transactions per second).
What is the way to test the UI screen for 300TPS (if 300 users hit the URL at same time whether current spec able to load the login screen)